# Is there a way to reference NEW/OLD value in MySQL trigger dynamically?

Tags: mysql, triggers, version

I am trying to implement versioning of rows in the database triggers. I have 2 tables:

1. addresses (id, city, street, country)
2. address_versions (id, object_changes)

I want to create a row in address_versions table every time a row from addresses table is changed.

I created a following trigger:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER `addresses_after_create` AFTER INSERT ON `addresses` FOR EACH ROW
    this_trigger:BEGIN
    DECLARE object_changes_json JSON;

    -- Prepare object_changes JSON for address_versions row creation
    SET object_changes_json = JSON_OBJECT();

    IF COALESCE(OLD.city, '') <> COALESCE(NEW.city, '') THEN
        SET object_changes_json = JSON_SET(object_changes_json, '$.city', JSON_ARRAY(OLD.city, NEW.city));
    END IF;

    IF COALESCE(OLD.street, '') <> COALESCE(NEW.street, '') THEN
        SET object_changes_json = JSON_SET(object_changes_json, '$.street', JSON_ARRAY(OLD.street, NEW.street));
    END IF;

    IF COALESCE(OLD.country, '') <> COALESCE(NEW.country, '') THEN
        SET object_changes_json = JSON_SET(object_changes_json, '$.country', JSON_ARRAY(OLD.country, NEW.country));
    END IF;

    INSERT INTO address_versions (object_changes)
    VALUES (object_changes_json);
```

So every time I change a row in addresses table, the address_versions row is created with JSON of changed values.

But the problem with the above solution is that I need to update the trigger every time I add/remove a column to the table.

Is there a way to do it more dynamically?

I tried to create a separate table with column names and loop through it but I cannot access NEW/OLD values dynamically

```sql
...
    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH cursor_column_name INTO column_name_string;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;
        IF COALESCE(OLD.column_name_string, '') <> COALESCE(NEW.column_name_string, '') THEN
            SET object_changes_json = JSON_SET(object_changes_json, '$.additional_info', JSON_ARRAY(OLD.column_name_string, NEW.column_name_string));
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
...
```

But it failed with:

```
=> ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'column_name_string' in 'OLD'
```

Is there a way to dynamically reference NEW/OLD values?

Comment: 'Is there a way to dynamically reference NEW/OLD values?' - no there isn't - it's a change control exercise.

Comment: *`IF COALESCE(OLD.city, '') <> COALESCE(NEW.city, '') THEN`* Use more clear `IF NOT (OLD.city <=> NEW.city) THEN`.

Answer (score 2):

No. Cursors return data values (strings/numerics/dates/etc.), not identifiers. You can't use a string as an identifier without using dynamic SQL.

But in a trigger, you're not allowed to use dynamic SQL.

So you need to deploy updated trigger(s) at the same time you add or drop a column.

I acknowledge that's quite difficult to do without downtime.

The alternative is to update your `address_versions` using application code after you update the `addresses` table.

Comment: *I acknowledge that's quite difficult to do without downtime.* It usually takes longer to add/remove a column than it does to alter a trigger. Additionally - when adding a column, there is no problem if the old trigger is used for a while, and when deleting a column, the new trigger may work with the old structure for a while. So the downtime will be small, maybe even zero.

Comment: @Akina, Also there is no atomic replace trigger statement. You must drop the old trigger and create the new trigger. In the moment in between drop and create, you could miss some changes. So the downtime cannot be zero.

Comment: MySQL allows to create two triggers which acts on-by-one. So we simply create new trigger then drop old one (of course the trigger name will change but this effects nothing). A lot of actions will be logged twice, in old and new format, but I doubt that this is a problem.

Comment: You can doubt it all you like, but it depends on the OP's requirements, not your assumptions. :-)